# How to write match results from .cypher into textfile via cypher shell (Windows)?

Tags: cypher, cypher-shell

I want to write match results based on cypher code inside a cypher file via cypher-shell into a text file (I am trying to do this on Windows). The cypher file contains: 
`:begin`
`match(n) return n;`
`:commit`

I tried to execute:
`type x.cypher | cypher-shell.bat -u user -p secret > output.txt`
 I get no error. But at the end there is just an empty text file "output.txt" inside the bin folder. Testing the cypher code directly in the cypher-shell (without piping) works. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Be clearer: do you mean that you are trying to do this *on* Windows or do you mean that the text file *is encoded* in Windows?

Comment: I am trying to do this on Windows (I updated my question).

Comment: Are you using the powershell or the older one?

Comment: It is the older one

Comment: It is because the cypher-shell.bat does not output anything (let alone does not output on the terminal), so there is nothing to redirect on the file. (Do not mistake "show" for "output")

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for the information!

Answer (score 0):

consider using the apoc library

that you can export to different formats, maybe it can help you.

- Export to CSV
- Export to JSON
- Export to Cypher Script
- Export to GraphML
- Export to Gephi

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/xx/export/ --> xx your version Neo4j,example 4.0